# Jobscheduler API android L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-jobscheduler

I am making an application that makes use of the jobscheduler API.
I want to run a service periodically and when the device is charged. This is the code.

```
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(kJobId++, mServiceComponent);
                    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
                    builder.setPeriodic(3000);
                    builder.setRequiresCharging(true);
                    mTestService.scheduleJob(builder.build());
```

Now when I run this and I unplug the device, the service still runs after 3 secs. There is no effect of setting the setRequiresCharging.

When i comment out builder.setPeriodic(3000), it works perfectly fine. I am not sure as to where I am going wrong.

Comment: Maybe job scheduler isn't combining those conditions the way you do? Like OR instead of AND. Or maybe they forgot about such cornercases. The documentation is not clear about the behavior of those conditions.

Comment: If you use builder.setMinimumLatency(5000) along with builder.setOverrideDeadline(60000), it works considering the condition (I tested with wifi condition), so maybe there's something special about setPeriodic method which tells it to ignore the constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To identify each job internally, the framework creates a new [`JobStatus`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/JobStatus.java) when a new job lands on the scheduler. One of the first things `JobStatus` does is to check and see if your job has a periodic update interval. If it does, it uses the [periodic update interval](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/app/job/JobInfo.java#L167) to determine the latest point in the future that a job must be run, or in other words, [if it has a deadline constraint.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/JobStatus.java#L177)

One of the criteria for a job to be considered [ready to be executed](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/JobSchedulerService.java#L634), it that all of its constraints have been satisfied **or** the deadline of a job has expired. See [`JobStatus.isReady`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/JobStatus.java#L201) for more information.

The `JobSchedulerService` adds several [`StateController`s](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/StateController.java) used to track when jobs should run and when they must be stopped. One of these controllers is a [`TimeController`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/TimeController.java), which:

> sets an alarm for the next expiring job, and determines whether a
>   job's minimum delay has been satisfied

[To determine if a new alarm should be scheduled](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/TimeController.java#L91), `TimeController` checks if your job has any time delay or deadline constraints, which all jobs seem to be given if you set a periodic update interval.

I hope that helps you at least understand *why* your job continues being scheduled despite your battery constraint. But I don't have a solution that can offer a straightforward fix for this at the moment.

Comment: So from my understanding there is no check being done for any criteria when it is periodic ? I am a little confused.

Comment: @Rohit_Ramkumar It's a little confusing for me too, but that's what the source seems to indicate. `JobStatus.isReady` checks for any constraints, then checks for deadline constraints. After reviewing the source, does it not seem that way to you?

Comment: Absolutely. Now I get it but don't understand why they have done this. Thank you.

Comment: Reported this issue. Here is the link

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81265