# Android JobScheduler: JobService with network constraint start even if my device have no network connection.

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I try to implement JobScheduler in my app, but I have an issue that I can't understand.

The goal is to start a service when internet connection is available on my device, within interval of 10 secondes.

So i use a JobScheduler in this way:

```
    JobScheduler mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1, new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
            MyJobService.class.getName()))
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setPeriodic(10 * 1000);


    if (mJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build()) <= 0) {
        Log.e("gch", "can't Schedule job for MyJobService");
    } else {
        Log.d("gch", "Schedule job for MyJobService");
    }
```

And my JobService:

```
public class MyJobService extends android.app.job.JobService {
    public MyJobService() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d("gch", "onStartJob");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d("gch", "onStartonStopJob");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Of course I added the `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"`

If I understand properly, my JobService should be executed only if my device have network, and at most once within 10s.

But, on my device, I have no internet connection (no SIM card inserted, and WIFI is not able) BUT my job is executed every 10s..
It seems NETWORK_TYPE_ANY is ignored. Same issue with NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED.

Somebody already facing to this issue ?

Thank a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jobscheduler API android L](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208776/jobscheduler-api-android-l)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread: 
[Jobscheduler API android L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208776/jobscheduler-api-android-l)

and this bugreport:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81265

The time is seen as a deadline, when this deadline is reached the job will trigger although your other constraints aren't met. I don't know if it's a bug or a feature.